# How to disable an Item in listbox even when it has Multi-select mode in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, disable

I am working on creating a header inside the listbox which will turn gray and will have a colon in it while the rest of the entries  (listbox items) will be black.

What I am trying to do is that if the value matches one of the types in the list string then it will turn gray and become header. After it becomes a header, I would like to disable the itembox making it unclickable while the rest of the entries are clickable.

Here is my function:

```
private void PopulateItems(List<string> items, string groupName)
{
    listbx.Items.Clear();

    List<string> itemsList = items;
    string founditemtype = null;

    foreach (string item in items)
    {
        foreach (string itemtype in Type)
        {
            if(item == itemtype)
            {
                founditemtype = itemtype;
                Label label = new Label();
                label.Content = itemtype + ":";
                label.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                label.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;

                // Handle the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event to prevent the grayed text to be selected:
                label.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (label.Content.ToString().Contains(":"))
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                };

                listbx.Items.Add(label);
            }
        }

        if(item != founditemtype)
        {
            listbx.Items.Add(item);
        }
}
```

Here is the WPf of my listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbx" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="525" Height="200" SelectionMode="Multiple" />
```

However, every time I run the application the listbox always allows the user to select the items that should be greyed out making it clickable and selected. Even with the multi-selection mode turned on, it can still be selected when the user selects other items and by mistake selects the header item. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid working directly on the `ItemsControl.Items` property. Instead create a member variable that you can operate on.

Additionally, never add controls to an ItemsControl directly. This will drastically impair the performance (because doing so will disable UI virtuialization for the `ListBox`).

You can simplify your code by using the built-in behavior of all `UIElement` elements: when you set the `UIElement.IsEnabled` property on the `ListBoxItem` to `false`, the item container will be automatically disabled, means grayed out and not clickable.

To accomplish this you need access to the `ListBoxItem`.
Using a `MultiBinding` and a `IMultiValueConverter` can easily solve your problem, avoiding unnecessary iterations.

I also recommend to use data binding in general [Microsoft Learn: Data binding overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

If your original goal is to implement grouping, take a look at [Microsoft Learn: Collection Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#collection-views) and grouping.
The `ListBox` is able to automatically create groups for.

**ListBoxValueToHeaderConverter.cs**

```cs
public class ListBoxValueToHeaderConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    string currentItem = values
      .OfType<string>()
      .First();
    ListBoxItem currentItemContainer = values
      .OfType<ListBoxItem>()
      .First();
    IEnumerable<string> predicateCollection = values
      .OfType<IEnumerable<string>>()
      .First();
      
    if (predicateCollection.Contains(currentItem))
    {
      // Disable the item container to make it automatically not clickable
      // and to be rendered as grayed out
      currentItemContainer.IsEnabled = false;
      return ":";
    }

    return currentItem;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  // You should assign a new collection if you want to modify it.
  // This will update the MultiBinding (in XAML). 
  // In general, when binding an ItemsCOntrol to a collection 
  // prefer to clear/replace the items to improve the performance of the control. 
  // Because this collection is not the binding source for a control 
  // replacing in this scenario is fine.
  public ObservableCollection<string> Type { get; private set; }

  // Declare this property as public if you want to bind to it
  private ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; }

  public MainWindow(TestViewModel dataContext, INavigator navigator)
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    // It's generally recommended to use data binding instead of explicit assignment.
    this.ListBox.ItemsSource = this. Items;
  }

  private void PopulateItems(List<string> newItems, string groupName)
  {
    this.Items.Clear();
    newItems.ForEach(this.Items.Add);
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:ListBoxValueToHeaderConverter x:Key="ListBoxValueToHeaderConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <ListBox x:Name="ListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Content">
          <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ListBoxValueToHeaderConverter}">

              <!-- The current item -->
              <Binding />

              <!-- The item container (ListBoxItem) -->
              <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />

              <!-- The filter predicate collection defined in the parent Window --> 
              <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}"
                       Path="Type" />
            </MultiBinding>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Style.Triggers>
    
          <!-- Define a trigger to change the look of the disabled ListBoxItem -->
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                   Value="False">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                    Value="Bold" />
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that I understood correctly what you need.
But check this code:

```cs
    private HashSet<string> Type = new() {/* Some string type names */};
    private void PopulateItems(List<string> items, string groupName)
    {
        listbx.Items.Clear();

        //List<string> itemsList = items;
        //string founditemtype = null;

        foreach (string item in items)
        {
            //foreach (string itemtype in Type)
            //{
                //if (item == itemtype)
                if (Type.Contains(item))
                {
                    //founditemtype = itemtype;
                    Label label = new Label();
                    //label.Content = itemtype + ":";
                    label.Content = item+ ":";
                    label.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                    label.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;

                    //// Handle the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event to prevent the grayed text to be selected:
                    //label.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) =>
                    //{
                    //    if (label.Content.ToString().Contains(":"))
                    //    {
                    //        e.Handled = true;
                    //    }
                    //};

                    listbx.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem()
                    {
                        Content = label,
                        IsEnabled = false
                    });
                }
            //}

            //if (item != founditemtype)
            else
            {
                listbx.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```